# Swift Switching To and FromTable ViewController Issue Using Custom Segue

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift3, uistoryboardsegue

I have run into an issue when using a custom segue. I have two tableviews that I'm an trying to switch back and forth from. When I click on a cell in tableview1 it should take me to tableview2. I have a button on tableview2 that connects to the exit of the storyboard. From there it should take me back to tableview1 but whenever I press the button, the application crashes with a BAD_ACCESS error.

Here is my custom segue class:

```
class TableViewSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

override func perform() {
    scale()
}

func scale () {
   let toViewcontroller = self.destination
    let fromViewcontroller = self.source
    let containerView = fromViewcontroller.view.superview
    let originalCenter = fromViewcontroller.view.center
    toViewcontroller.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.05, y: 0.05)
    toViewcontroller.view.center = originalCenter

    containerView?.addSubview(toViewcontroller.view)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
    toViewcontroller.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
    }, completion: { success in
    fromViewcontroller.present(toViewcontroller, animated: false, completion: nil) //The application crashes and highlights this line as the error.
    }) 
} 

}
```

I have implemented this method in my tableViewController1:

```
    @IBAction func prepareForUnwind(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {

}
```

Not sure why the tableview2 does not dismiss.

EDIT: The issue had to do with needing a navigation controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are `presenting` the `toViewcontroller` each time a segue is performed. So the app presents table2 *over* table1, and then tries **again** to present table1 *over* table2 on the unwind.

Modify your custom segue to check - essentially - which direction you're going:

```
class TableViewSegue: UIStoryboardSegue {

    override func perform() {
        scale()
    }

    func scale () {
        let toViewcontroller = self.destination
        let fromViewcontroller = self.source
        let containerView = fromViewcontroller.view.superview
        let originalCenter = fromViewcontroller.view.center
        toViewcontroller.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0.05, y: 0.05)
        toViewcontroller.view.center = originalCenter

        containerView?.addSubview(toViewcontroller.view)

        let fromP = fromViewcontroller.presentingViewController

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0, options: .curveEaseInOut, animations: {
            toViewcontroller.view.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        }, completion: { success in

            // if nil, we are presenting a new VC
            if fromP == nil {
                fromViewcontroller.present(toViewcontroller, animated: false, completion: nil)
            } else {
                fromViewcontroller.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
            }

        })
    }

}
```

**Note:** This is assuming:

1. you are *not* trying to push/pop within a `UINavigationController` ... you'd need to add some other checks to handle that.
2. you are only going one-level-in, that is, you are *not* presenting, presenting, presenting, etc. and *then* trying to unwind.

Comment: This is part of a login application so the issue i have with this code is that when I call the segue, it presents the second tableview but then immediately logs out of the application because the dismiss function dismisses the whole view, going back to the login viewcontroller not tableview controller1. Do you have any idea how to fix that?

Comment: You'll need to be a little more clear on your VC hierarchy and what exactly you want to do. Your initial question was *"take me back to tableview1"* so I don't really know else what you have going on.

Comment: There is a login uiviewcontroller which takes the user to TableVC1. From there I click on a cell and takes me to tableVC2. If i call the dismiss function, it dismisses back to the login viewcontroller not to TableVC1.

Comment: *"takes the user to TableVC1"* ??? How? Push onto a navigation controller? Replace the current VC? Shows it as a childController / subview? You have to be ***clear*** on how you have your view controllers structured if you want more help than what's already been given you.

Comment: oh sorry about that. From the login view controller, it pushes to tableVC1. No navigation controller used in the project. Once at tableVC1, a cell is selected and the custom segue is used above to get to tableVC2. In tableVC2, there is a back button which I have connected to the exit in storyboard. When I press the back button it should use the custom segue with that exit connection. So, there is no segue in storyboard connecting the exit button back to tableVC1 because from my understanding, the exit connection should automatically dismiss tableVC2. However, that is not my case.

Comment: *"...it pushes to tableVC1. No navigation controller used..."* You only **push** with Navigation Controllers, so your app is NOT pushing to table VC1. Is the login controller *presenting* VC1? If so, do you *want* that to be the case, that "login view" will forever be the base / underlying view of your app, and everything else is overlaid on top of it?